# Recursive search object for value

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, map-function

Consider this object:

```
pa = {
  "133": {
    "B": null,
    "C": {
      "A": null,
      "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895085713162"
    }
  },
  "134": {
    "B": null,
    "C": {
      "A": null,
      "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895111043714"
    }
  },
  "135": {
    "B": null,
    "C": {
      "A": null,
      "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895094505523"
    }
  },
  "136": {
    "B": null,
    "C": {
      "A": null,
      "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895096452313"
    }
  }
};
```

I would like to create an array of the URLs. Normally I could do something like
this:

```
qu = keys(pa).map(ro => pa[ro].C.o);
```

However the keys `A`, `B`, `C` and `o` can change. Can I create this array
another way? I thought of doing a recursive RegEx for `http:`, but I am not sure
how to implement that.

Comment: Why do the keys change? Sounds like it'd be easier to fix that problem and use `map` as you've already proposed

Comment: This doc answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/188/objects/5944/iterate-through-each-property-of-an-object#t=201607250134129920974

Comment: @Zze no, that method does not recurse

Comment: @Sierra `for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}` - recursion not needed ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/\w+\?\w+=\d+/g` to match `"http:"` followed by two forward slashes, by word, dot, word, forward slash, word, question mark character, word, equal sign, followed by digits.

Or, as suggested by @Sierra `http:[^"]+`.

```js
var pa = { "133": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895085713162" } }, "134": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895111043714" } }, "135": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895094505523" } }, "136": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895096452313" } } };

var arr = JSON.stringify(pa).match(/http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/\w+\?\w+=\d+/g);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Couldn’t you just do `http:[^"]+`?

Comment: @Sierra Yes. How would you describe `RegExp`? Match `http:` followed by any character except `"`?

Answer (score 3):

Just search it recursively. Here is an example:

```js
var pa = { "133": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895085713162" } }, "134": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895111043714" } }, "135": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895094505523" } }, "136": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895096452313" } } };

function searchUrl(obj, result) {
    if (typeof result == 'undefined') {
        result = []
    }
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'string' || obj[key] instanceof String) {
                  if (obj[key].startsWith('http://')) {
                        result.push(obj[key]); // handle the url here
                  }
            } else if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                  searchUrl(obj[key], result);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(searchUrl(pa));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pa = { "133": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895085713162" } }, "134": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895111043714" } }, "135": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895094505523" } }, "136": { "B": null, "C": { "A": null, "o": "http://example.com/upn?lmt=1423895096452313" } } };

var urls = [];
function findUrls(obj) {
    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "string") {
            if (obj[key].startsWith("http") || obj[key].startsWith("ftp")) {
                urls.push(obj[key]);
            }
        } else if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            findUrls(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}

findUrls(pa);

console.log(urls); // array of urls
```